# How to Load when scrolled to bottom

Tags: reactjs

Hello im creating a movie app and everything is there except how do i put infinitescroll in my file? i want when scroll to bottom a new poster will appear.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MovieCard from '../Components/MovieCard'


function Home() {
  const url =
    "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=328c283cd27bd1877d9080ccb1604c91&release_dates.lte=2016-12-31&sort_by=release_date.desc&page=1";
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>
        setMovies({ data: data.results, loading: false, error: false })
      );
  }, []);

  return  (  
    
    <>
      {movies.data.map((movie) => (
          <MovieCard 
            movie={movie}
          />
      ))} 

 
    </>

  )
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: An already premade InfiniteScroll element might be more efficient to implement, try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple and you can do it without any external libraries

1. Add some element at the end of the page, for example empty div (or use any existing element)
2. Add [react reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to that element
3. Add scroll event listener to the window, where you compare if user scrolled beyond that element.

This could look something like this:

```
  const refLastElement = useRef()

  const checkScrollEnd = useCallback(() => {
    if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= refLastElement.current.offsetTop) {
      // add more elements
    }
  }, [/* something */])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScrollEnd)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScrollEnd)
  }, [checkScrollEnd])
```

Comment: where shall I put it inside the file? could you show me?